# Namespace attribute in configuration tag

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

We have a namespace attribute in configuration tag of config file.
Like

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v1.0">
```

What is its use?
What will its impact if I will remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration element is the required root element in every configuration file that is used by the common language runtime and the .NET Framework applications.
Each configuration file must contain exactly one configuration element.

For more details check [Refrence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228147(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I need details about schema URL, whats its use, why needed , not about configuration element